# Configuration settings in filedepot for folders

Tags: 7, users

How to setup permissions in [filedepot](https://drupal.org/project/filedepot) module?

I have 2 users like A and B.

User "A" can create the folders and he can upload the files into that folders, but folders and files should not show or share to user "B". User "B" be follow the same functionality.

Only user can view the owned files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a job for the [Content Access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) module?

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

Answer (score 0):

To make this happen,someone with "Administer Filedepot" rights (in /admin/people/permissions), needs to set up top level files for user A and user B (by clicking on the New Folder button). Then click on A's folder in the right-hand pane and click "Permissions". That brings up a dialog that you can use to assign permissions to specific users. (Select user A and check the box for Folder Admin then delete any other access records.) Repeat for User B.

From then on, each User will be able to upload and download files in their own folders and see no one else's.

You will also want to give authenticated users "Access Filedepot" rights in /admin/people/permissions or set up a role with those rights and assign A and B to that role.